# JPA Saves Entities Wrong

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate and DTO to save my entities that are `Test (tests)`, `TestQuestion (test_questions)` and `TestAnswer (test_answers)`.

I convert DTO to Hibernate entity by using [ModelMaper](http://modelmapper.org/). My entities are saved wrong:

1) The first issue is I set `User` object in Test entity after mapping is done. The JPA creates 2 entities in the `tests` table. One with user id, one without user id. `Question` list in the `Test` class is saved correctly in the `test_questions` table with the reference of test id whose user id is empty.

2) The second issue is `Answer` list in the `Question` class is not saved in `test_answers` table at all.

Tables:

[image: tables]

SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE tests (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () PRIMARY KEY,
    therapist_id UUID REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    level INTEGER NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    date_time_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_time_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE test_questions (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () PRIMARY KEY,
    test_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES tests (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    type TEST_TYPE_ENUM NOT NULL,
    question TEXT NOT NULL,
    audio TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    description TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    img TEXT NOT NULL,
    cloud_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_time_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_time_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE test_answers (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 () PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES test_questions (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    answer TEXT NOT NULL,
    audio TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    img TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    cloud_id TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_time_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_time_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Test class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tests")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2184376232517605961L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    private String description;

    private Integer level = 0;

    private Boolean active = false;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_created")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeCreated = new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_updated")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeUpdated = new Date();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "therapist_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "test", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TestQuestion> questions = new HashSet<>();

    // getters-setters



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", level=" + level +
                ", active=" + active +
                ", dateTimeCreated=" + dateTimeCreated +
                ", dateTimeUpdated=" + dateTimeUpdated +
                ", user=" + user.getId() +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Test test = (Test) o;
        return Objects.equal(id, test.id) &&
                Objects.equal(description, test.description) &&
                Objects.equal(level, test.level) &&
                Objects.equal(active, test.active) &&
                Objects.equal(dateTimeCreated, test.dateTimeCreated) &&
                Objects.equal(dateTimeUpdated, test.dateTimeUpdated) &&
                Objects.equal(user, test.user) &&
                Objects.equal(questions, test.questions);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id, description, level, active, dateTimeCreated, dateTimeUpdated, user, questions);
    }
}
```

TestQuestion class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_questions")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class TestQuestion implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6367504273687746576L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    private String question;

    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private TestQuestionTypeEnum type;

    private String img;

    private String audio;

    private String cloudId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_created")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeCreated = new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_updated")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeUpdated = new Date();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    private Test test;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TestAnswer> answers = new HashSet<>();

    // getters-setters

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TestQuestion{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", question='" + question + '\'' +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", type=" + type +
            ", img='" + img + '\'' +
            ", audio='" + audio + '\'' +
            ", cloudId='" + cloudId + '\'' +
            ", dateTimeCreated=" + dateTimeCreated +
            ", dateTimeUpdated=" + dateTimeUpdated +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    TestQuestion that = (TestQuestion) o;
    return Objects.equal(id, that.id) &&
            Objects.equal(question, that.question) &&
            Objects.equal(description, that.description) &&
            type == that.type &&
            Objects.equal(img, that.img) &&
            Objects.equal(audio, that.audio) &&
            Objects.equal(cloudId, that.cloudId) &&
            Objects.equal(dateTimeCreated, that.dateTimeCreated) &&
            Objects.equal(dateTimeUpdated, that.dateTimeUpdated) &&
            Objects.equal(test, that.test) &&
            Objects.equal(answers, that.answers);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(id, question, description, type, img, audio, cloudId, dateTimeCreated, dateTimeUpdated, test, answers);
}
}
```

TestAnswer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_answers")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class TestAnswer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2372807870272293491L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID id;

    private String answer;

    private String audio;

    private String img;

    private String cloudId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_created")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeCreated = new Date();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_time_updated")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date dateTimeUpdated = new Date();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private TestQuestion question;

// getters-setters



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestAnswer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", answer='" + answer + '\'' +
                ", audio='" + audio + '\'' +
                ", img='" + img + '\'' +
                ", cloudId='" + cloudId + '\'' +
                ", dateTimeCreated=" + dateTimeCreated +
                ", dateTimeUpdated=" + dateTimeUpdated +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TestAnswer that = (TestAnswer) o;
        return Objects.equal(id, that.id) &&
                Objects.equal(answer, that.answer) &&
                Objects.equal(audio, that.audio) &&
                Objects.equal(img, that.img) &&
                Objects.equal(cloudId, that.cloudId) &&
                Objects.equal(dateTimeCreated, that.dateTimeCreated) &&
                Objects.equal(dateTimeUpdated, that.dateTimeUpdated) &&
                Objects.equal(question, that.question);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id, answer, audio, img, cloudId, dateTimeCreated, dateTimeUpdated, question);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Component("testService")
@Transactional
public class TestService extends Helper {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestService.class);

    private final TestRepository testRepository;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public TestService(TestRepository testRepository, UserService userService, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.testRepository = testRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public Test createTest(TestDTO testDTO) {

        User teacher = userService.findById(getLoggedUserId());

        Test test = toTest(testDTO, modelMapper);
        test.setUser(teacher);

        test = testRepository.saveAndFlush(test);

        return test;
    }

    private Test toTest(TestDTO testDTO, ModelMapper modelMapper) {

        Test test = new Test();
        Set<TestQuestion> testQuestions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        TestValidity.validate(testDTO);

        testDTO.getQuestions().forEach(q -> {
            TestQuestion question = toQuestion(q, modelMapper);

            Set<TestAnswer> answers = toAnswerSet(q.getAnswers(), modelMapper);
            question.setAnswers(answers);

            testQuestions.add(question);
        });

        test.setQuestions(testQuestions);

        return test;
    }

    private TestQuestion toQuestion(TestQuestionDTO questionDTO, ModelMapper modelMapper) {


        return modelMapper.map(questionDTO, TestQuestion.class);
    }

    private Set<TestAnswer> toAnswerSet(Set<TestAnswerDTO> answerDTOSet, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        Set<TestAnswer> answers = new HashSet<>();
        answerDTOSet.forEach(a -> {

            TestAnswer answer = modelMapper.map(a, TestAnswer.class);

            answers.add(answer);
        });


        return answers;
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? I am not sure if those issues are because of `ModelMapper, because this is the first time I am using it. How can I save my entities correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're declaring the `cascade`'s on the wrong sides of the associations. From the Hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-unidirectional):

> The @OneToMany association is by definition a parent association, even if it’s a unidirectional or a bidirectional one. Only the parent side of an association makes sense to cascade its entity state transitions to children.

I believe that's the reason for your second issue since you have cascades declared on the child entity `TestAnswer` instead of the parent `TestQuestion`. When you create a `TestAnswer` the parent `TestQuestion` isn't aware that it needs to persist its children.

It's also possible the the first issue is due to both `Test` and `TestQuestion` having cascades declared on each side (both on the `@ManyToOne` pointing to `Test` and the `OneToMany` pointing to `TestQuestion`), since that may cause `tests` to be created once when you call `saveAndFlush()`, and once more when `TestQuestion` is created and sees that it needs to cascade-persist its parent entity `Test`.

Another issue is that you're not synchronizing both sides of the association when you're saving. According to one of the Hibernate devs [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/):

> However, we still need to have both sides in sync as otherwise, we break the Domain Model relationship consistency, and the entity state transitions are not guaranteed to work unless both sides are properly synchronized.

In other words, you'd need to do something along the lines of:

```
test.setUser(teacher);
teacher.getTests().add(test);
```

and similarly for `TestQuestion`:

```
testQuestions.add(question);
question.setTest(test);
```

and again something similar for the `TestAnswer`.

The linked Vlad Mihalcea blog shows a better way of doing this by adding a `addTestAnswer()` method directly to the `TestQuestion` entity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I understand correctly, I need to set cascade to parent side which means I should set cascade to `@OneToMany`, instead of `@ManyToOne`. This caused a `TransientPropertyValueException`: `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.project.model.TestQuestion.test -> com.project.model.Test; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Or if I set cascade(`CascadeType.ALL`) to `@ManyToOne`s and remove from `@OneToMany`, Test is recorded to `tests` table, but `test_question` and `test_answers` tables are empty.

Comment: You understood correctly, cascade should be on the `@OneToMany`. When you moved it to `@ManyToOne` the same thing happens that you mention in your second issue. It's not immediately clear to me why you're getting that error; cascading on the parent side is what's supposed to prevent exactly that (hibernate should be persisting the parent then cascading the children). I assume that moving `cascade = ... ` was the only thing that was changed?

Comment: Yes, I just moved cascade from `@OneToMany` to `@ManyToOne`. I couldn't find why I keep getting that error. Can it be because of `ModelMapper`? It may not map correctly or something?

Comment: I also added cascade to all (both `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` and it throws an error saying ` null value in column "question_id" violates not-null constraint`...

Comment: @Eniss Something else I've noticed is that you're not synchronizing both sides of the association. I've updated my answer with how to do that. Also, since you're already using `@Transactional` try removing `test = testRepository.saveAndFlush(test);` (no need to replace it with anything). This may resolve the `TransientPropertyValueException` if synching the associations doesn't do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. With small changes, I managed to save my entities. Thanks once again! I have 2 more questions. First one is I get stackoverflow if I override hashcode and equals methods. Should I not override them in a hibernate entitiy? I put my `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in the question Second one is if I need to update a question or just an answer, how should I do that?

Comment: No, overriding hashcode and equals is always a good idea in entities. Stackoverflow can be caused by any number of reasons, you'll have to do some debugging to figure out what's causing it. Updating is the repository's responsibility, see how Hibernate's EntityManager does it, or even better try to use Spring Data JPA to handle those methods for you.

Comment: Thank you once again. The error shows lists as stackoverflow. I'll debug deeper to understand the error. Thank you again!